# Return data from self loopoing method in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am writing a **windows phone 8.1 (winrt)** app. I have to get **StorageFile** from path (**string**).
I am entering into subfolders till I get file using this method iteratively. (Method loops till it finds storageFile)

But how to return this storageFile?
It returns **null** from first run(loop).

```
 public static async Task<StorageFile> GetStorageFileAsync(StorageFolder currentFolder, string filePath)
        {
            StorageFile file = null;
            if (FileHelper.IfPathContainDirectory(filePath))
            {
                // Just get the folder.
                string subFolderName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);

                bool isSubFolderExist = await FileHelper.IfFolderExistsAsync(currentFolder, subFolderName);

                StorageFolder subFolder=null;

                if (isSubFolderExist)
                { 
                    // Just get the folder.
                    subFolder =
                        await currentFolder.GetFolderAsync(subFolderName);
                }
                else
                {
                   return null;
                }

                string newFilePath = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newFilePath))
                {
                    //get file iteratively.
                    await GetStorageFileAsync(subFolder, newFilePath);
                }
                return file;
            }
            else
            {

                try
                {
                    file = await currentFolder.GetFileAsync(filePath);
                }
                catch(Exception fileExp)
                {

                }

                return file;
            }
        }
```

It enters into method, checks for presence of subfolder in path string
and gets deeper into that subfolder, and at last enters into else part
of condition and gets file. It doesnt return this file, but it returns
object null from first execution of loop.

Comment: You can pass a 3rd parameter that is a StorageFile type (ref) and just assign to it once you find it.

Comment: Async methods cannot have ref or out parameters :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot assigning the `file` variable:

```
await GetStorageFileAsync(subFolder, newFilePath);
```

should be

```
file = await GetStorageFileAsync(subFolder, newFilePath);
```

Didn't try the code, but that would be an obvious reason of the result being `null`.